# Scheme: Arrow -> What does it mean?

Tags: syntax, scheme

I'm taking a functional programming course, using the book SICP as reference. Several places in the book, I have come across the use of **'->' arrows** in procedure definitions.

Examples:

```
(define (segments->painter segment-list)
    (lambda ...

(define (tree->list tree)
    (if (...

(define (scheme-number->complex n)
    (make-complex-from-real ...
```

So, what does the '->' arrow mean? Is it a naming convention to indicate that the procedure transforms one thing into another; such as tree-into-list?
If not; what does the **arrow** represent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As @sepp2k mentions -> is part of the name and doesn't mean anything in it self.
The convention is to use -> in names for "conversion" (used loosely) functions.
The function `string->list` has a string as input and produces a list of characters.

In most cases you can pronounce `->` as "to". That is `string->list` is pronounced "string to list" if you were to read code aloud.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it a naming convention to indicate that the procedure transforms one thing into another; such as tree-into-list?

Exactly.

Comment: Thank you, @sepp2k!
To see if I get this right: The arrow in itself, when used in say "(define (age->days-lived ...", does not do anything at all? 
It simply serves as an indication that said procedure will convert the age to the number of days lived.

Comment: @northerner It's part of the name. Syntactically it holds no special significance.

Comment: It is a very common convention, used in the names of standard procedures such as `list->string` and `string->list`.